# How to upgrade clojure nrepl 0.2.6 to 0.2.7

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, nrepl

I have just installed Cider from melpa which has version 0.9.0 SNAPSHOT and nREpL 0.2.6. This more or less works once I used the profile suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688721/how-to-upgrade-nrepl-version-of-leiningen). However, this does not appear to work as the nrepl version is 0.2.6 still.

Here is my profiles.clj from .lein

```
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.7"]]}}
```

and this the warning I get

```
; CIDER 0.9.0snapshot (package: 20150318.555) (Java 1.6.0_65, Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.6)
WARNING: CIDER requires nREPL 0.2.7 to work properly
```

Any hints appreciated, or maybe this does not matter?

EDIT: The version of lein is 2.5.1

Further Edit: Note that I asked this question as the referenced stackoverflow question does not appear to solve the problem. This is a brand new install for clojure so its not clear if thjis is a singificant issue or not for me. Cheers

Comment: That link is already contained in this question. This question is about why the answer to that question does not work in this case. I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: could you include the lein version as well?

Comment: for those that stumble across this, the solution was to delete the .m2 repository and download everything again with the profiles.clj in place in the .lien directory. That way the old version of the mrepl is not included and all works after that